# Contents of variables are unexpectedly changing?

Tags: c, variables

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

main()
{
    int h, m;
    char designator[] = "";

    printf("Please enter the hours: ");
    scanf("%d", &h);
    if (h < 0 || h > 23)
    {
        printf("Please enter a proper time!");
    }

    else
    {
        printf("Please enter the minutes: ");
        scanf("%d", &m);
        if (m > 59 || m < 0)
        {
            printf("Please enter a proper time!");
        }

        else if (h == 0 && m == 0) 
        {
            strcpy(designator, "midnight");
        }
        else if (h == 12 && m == 0) 
        {
            strcpy(designator, "noon");
        }
        else if (h == 0)
        {
            strcpy(designator, "am");
            h = h + 12;
        }
        else if (h < 12) 
        {
            strcpy(designator, "am");
        }
        else if (h > 12)
        {
            strcpy(designator, "pm");
            h = h - 12;
        }
        printf("The time is: %d:%d %s", h, m, designator);
    }
}
```

Hello there! When I run this code, I get an output that is very unexpected. The variables (m in particular) are not supposed to change. They are taken as input using scanf() but I have no intentions of changing them. I assume the variables have the problem or with the if's but really I have no idea what the problem is with my code :/

This is what appears in the command line:

> Please enter the hours: 23
>   Please enter the minutes: 15
>   The time is: 11:109 pm

I have tried to identify where the "109" is coming from but I have no clue whatsoever. I'm very new to C so there's probably some things that are not clear to me yet but I'm very willing to learn of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do `sizeof designator` you will see that it has a size of only *one* byte. Its contents will be the the single character `'\0'` (the string terminator). That's because of the way you initialize it.

If you create an array without an explicit size, the compiler will deduce the size from whatever data you use to initialize the array with. Since you initialize it with an empty string, an empty string is what it will contain and that's the size it will have.

Because of this you will write out of bounds of the array, and that will lead to *undefined behavior*.

You need to explicitly set a size of the array, large enough to contain the largest string you will copy into it.

E.g.

```
char designator[128] = "";
```

Comment: And is there any reason why the designator variable affected the other variables? Or is it just the undefined behavior that you mentioned there?

Comment: @NugNugs The underlying reason is that all local variables are stored on the CPU core stack, and taking up just enough space as decided by the compiler. That means when you write out of bounds of the array, you might overwrite the memory of the stack where the other variables are stored.

Answer (score 0):

The value of the numeric variables might change, as you are copying bytes to a location (`designator`) without sufficient space which may overwrite them.